# Make grails to run locally (intranet)

Tags: maven, grails, local, artifactory, run-app

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535310/how-to-run-grails-fully-locally), I have to say that I am in the exact same situation.

I can use USB keys to transfert files from the internet on my computer, but my computer could not access to the Internet.

So my question is : how set up my computer environment to make grails compile and run the first time without Internet ?

Which packages do I have to download, how to create my folder, and configure my build.gradle to make it running ? (when I want to visit [maven repository](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core), I see a looooot of folder and subfolder, and so on.
Do I have to create the same arborescence ?
Do I have to download it all ?
Does it existe any software to make it automatically ? (scrappy ?)

Anny tutorial, help is welcome, and I am ready to create a full tutorial when (if) I finally achieve this.

Thanks in advance !

(At this point, I create the war file for my project on a machine with internet access and make it running on the intranet computer with tomcat, but this solution is not satisfaying for developpement)

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is : how set up my computer environment to make grails compile and run the first time without Internet ?

Basically we need internet connection to download required dependencies/jars from remote location(Maven). And even our Maven comes already with a local repository`(~/.m2/repository)`

To Installs a packaged application or plugin into the local Maven cache use following command:

```
grails maven-install [--binary]
```

Please check documentation [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/ref/Command%20Line/maven-install.html)

In your new application do modify below details:

**Local Resolvers**

If you do not wish to use a public Maven repository you can specify a flat file repository:

```
repositories {
    flatDir name:'myRepo', dirs:'/path/to/repo'
}
```

To specify your local Maven cache (~/.m2/repository) as a repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Please refer [this](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.3/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories) and [this](https://appmediation.com/how-to-add-local-libraries-to-gradle/) for all details and documentation

[This](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9393) is similar issue someone raised in grails repo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seem that "local resolver" is the best answer. My question is : if I duplicate all the folder, subfolder, and files on "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/", put them on a local folder on my computer (usb transfer), and use the "flatDir" directive linked to my local copy of https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/, will it work ? I will try this this and let you know tomorow.

Comment: @Snite Please try and let me know also. :)

Comment: The copy of the repositorie with wget did not work, I used the following command : wget -r -l=inf --no-parent --reject "index.html" https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
On the first folder ".m2e" instead of subfolder I only have a file named index.htm.tmp"
I create a new post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435311/recursive-copy-of-grails-maven-repository-with-wget

Comment: @Snite if my answer help you solve problem or way to solve problem. please accept answer!!