# Recursive copy of grails maven repository with wget

Tags: grails, wget, maven-repository

This post is part of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419472/make-grails-to-run-locally-intranet)

I want to copy this repository on my local computer : https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/

To achieve my goal, I ran all night long this wget command :

```
wget -r -l=inf --no-parent --reject "index.html" https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

This morning, the wget command was ended, and I went into ".m2e", and instead of having the subfolders "connectors" and "discovery_catalog" as expected, I have an "index.htm.tmp" file.

Same on all the folders (".meta", ".nexus", ".report", and so on).

How can I mirror this maven repository using wget ? Is wget the right tool for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have thousands and thousands of artifacts in repo.grails.org, many of them only useful in versions of Grails that have been EOL for many years.  There is really no good reason for you to try and mirror the entire repository in that way.

Comment: In wich file can I found the artifact needed for my Grails version ? (4.0.1)
So I can create a .bat script to retrieve only the needed one

Comment: There is no particular file in which you will find that list. One way to identify what is needed is to build an app on an internet connected machine and then copy the artifact cache contents.

Comment: Sorry if the question is stupid, but... where can I find the artifact cache content ?
Furthermore, when I copy .m2 and .graddle folders from an internet connected machine and put them on my intranet machine, the build fail because grails still try to access grails.repo.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to an Internet connection error.
I tried the same command on a subfolder and all worked as expected.
Sorry for the question, due to the massive amount of data on core grails repository, the script crashed and I thought it was ended.